# ValueError: The view selection.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I currently work with student management system by using django. in that I found some errors. Anybody can help me.

view.py

```
def register(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_user = form.save(commit=False)
                new_user.save()
                Student.objects.create(user=new_user)
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                user = authenticate(request,username=cd['username'],password=cd['password1'])
                if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                        return redirect('login/edit/')
                    else:
                        return HttpResponse('Disabled account')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Invalid Login')
        else:
            form = UserForm()
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'reg_form.html', args)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2']
        help_texts = {
            'username': 'same as your roll no.',
        }
```

The code doesn't have any errors. It works fine. After filling the form, I click register button. It will functioning and post request also done but returning null value.
Anybody can fix this.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if it "doesn't have errors" then what is the problem ? what are you expecting to receive back please ?

Comment: I have the same error, but I'm using `def post(self, request, **kwargs):`.